# Unity(2020,3,11f1) Physic material no se puede añadir

Tags: c#, unity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy haciendo un juego y hay una pared con un box collider 2d que hice, por la friccion si me acerco a la pared y dejo presionado espacio y derecha o izquierda(depende si la pared esta en la derecha o izquierda) se queda pillado hasta que lo suelte, supe que si usas un Physic material se soluciona pero al querer meterlo al apartado MATERIAL de los colliders no aparece, he intentado mover el physic material a otras carpetas ya sea texturas, scripts ,etc pero aparece como si no pudiera importarlo a Material

Comment: No necesitas abrir oootra pregunta. Con editar la que se cerró (como lo indica el mensaje que tiene encima) bastaba. Además, esa ya tenía atención de la gente. Para que recuerdes que, si te comentamos sobre el contenido de la pregunta, no es para molestarte sino para ayudarte a crear una pregunta que otros puedan responder de forma efectiva y recibas ayuda más rápido.

Comment: ok la proxima lo hare, cual es la respuesta a mi pregunta?

Comment: Ni idea, no sé nada de c# ni de unity y espero que los que saben en el sitio vengan a ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente esto se deba a que tu juego esta en 2D y has creado un physic material 3D. Para hacerlo 2D tienes que: click derecho, create, 2D, physic material 2D. Espero te haya servido

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/389374)